# How to install now.js on Windows

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm trying to install now.js on Windows using the node package manager but I get errors. Here's what I have:
[image]

Can you tell me what's wrong with my installation? I supposed all the dependencies are already being fetched before installing now.js That's why I didn't do `npm install node-proxy` and `npm install socket.io`

Comment: I did some research and came across this issue: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/issues/28 what it says is that now.js can't be installed on Windows. But I was able to install it before on node version 0.6.7.

Comment: and there's also this one: http://botsikas.blogspot.com/2011/12/building-native-modules-for-nodejs-06.html I have visual studio 2010 installed before(maybe that's the reason I made it work last time?) But I don't need it anymore so I uninstalled it. Is there any way to make this work on Windows without installing a big software such as visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows developers trying to install now js. Here's the answer:
http://blog.nowjs.com/running-nowjs-natively-on-windows

Sometimes it's really useful to look on the issues at the projects github page

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it looks like you're missing the 'make' command.  You can download a full suite of tools from cygwin.com.  Pay attention to the following:

http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.what-packages

Answer (score 1):

Currently `now` isn't supported on Windows although they are working on it ([see their issues](https://github.com/Flotype/now/issues/185)). The issue does say there is a branch which you can install but it seems to then break on `node-proxy`.

You may be able to work around it using cygwin but npm doesn't support cygwin and I remember having a lot of problems with it.

I'd say your best bet (if you can't install a Linux VM or use a Mac) is to check out [Cloud9](http://c9.io) and use that for development.